# Introduction to AI Robotics book: robot implementation, with ROS?

Tags: ros, artificial-intelligence, books

I'm reading the book [Introduction to AI Robotics](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-ai-robotics) By Robin R. Murphy and it the first character said, more or less, that after chapter 5 I will be able to design and implement my own robots, either in a real robot or in simulation.

I don't have a lot of money to buy the components to implement a robot, so I want to do it in simulation.

My question is: where I can do a robot simulation?

I've found ROS is suitable for this but I'm not sure. Is a good idea to use ROS with this book?

I have no idea about how to do it or what do I need because this is the first time I do something with robotics.

I have also found this [Virtual Simulator For Robots](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/deep-learning-ai/industries/robotics/).

Comment: How complex do you want to start? So what sensors and actuators?

Comment: I have no idea. This the first time I do something with robotics.

Comment: But you at least should have an idea of what kind of AI you want to do at least. Do you want to start with path finding for example?

Comment: I'm studying an Advanced Artificial Intelligence Master's degree and this book is for a subject of it. Yes, path finding looks like easy. I think I have to start with the easiest one.

Comment: Do you want to build your own world model from sensor data, have it given initially?

Comment: Ok. I have assumed that you have read the book and you know what I am talking about. This is also why I don't know how to answer your questions. In the book I have read something about world model and I suppose that is what I need to do, but I'm not sure. Sorry, I have just started to study the book. Thanks a lot of for your time and support.

Comment: I read this in the book: after chapter 5, I will be able to design and implement a reactive robot system, either in simulation or on a real robot. What does it mean with simulation? Using a simulator?

Comment: Yes, it means using a simulator.

Comment: I would also suggest that you build a very simple "hello world" robot in reality. There are a lot of "robot car" kits out that that run on an Arduino. It won't teach you much in the way of AI, but you'll learn about some of the real world problems that robots face.

Answer (score 1):

Some well-known simulators used in robotics include [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) (probably one of the most adopted), [Player/stage](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/) and [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots).

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials and forums to help in learning ROS. It can work on a Raspberry Pi, so you don't need an expensive computer to run Linux.

ROS includes (or is associated with) Gazebo, a robot simulator.

With ROS you get a lot of things involving movement that are easy to use. You also get drivers for many common sensors. You get SLAM and a few kinds of path planning.

What you don't get, as far as I know, is an overall goal planner. In other words, the AI part of the robot's brain. Which is good because you'll need to do that part as your degree. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [V-REP](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/index.html) for multiple reasons:

1. It is a robotics simulator with GUI.
2. It has many pre-installed robot models.
3. It works with ROS.
4. It has detailed tutorials and an official forum.

Check the demonstration video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBYqOBdIcaY&t=271s).